# Duplicating each column of a csv and changing values of every column cell based on a condition in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, csv

I am a new user to everything especially python and pandas. I have a .csv file with more than 1000 columns and around 250 rows. The values of the rows are either 0 and 1 or empty cells. An example of the csv file is given below:

```
  ID       col1   col2    col3  col4 .  . ............... col1000                          
  1          1     0              1                         1
  2          0              1     1                 
  3                1              0                         0                                                                   
  .
  .
  .
  .
 250         0     1              0                         0
```

There are two things that i want to do:

First, i want to duplicate all 1000 columns (except ID column) with same cell values and the column names as the original columns and then place each copied column next to the original column in the following order:

```
col1      col1     col2     col2    col3    col3     col4     col4 ...... col1000      col1000
```

Second, i want to replace the values in the cells based on on the following conditions:

If there is 1 in the original cell, The value in the copied column should remain 1 and if there is 0 in the original column cell then the value of the copied column should be changed to -1. If the original cell is empty then the value of original cell and the copied cell should be filled with 0 values.

The output csv file will be:

```
  ID     col1    col1   col2   col2   col3    col3   col4   col4 . ........... col1000   col1000                         
  1        1       1      0     -1      0       0      1      1                    1        1
  2        0      -1      0      0      1       1      1      1                    0        0
  3        0       0      1      1      0       0      0     -1                    0       -1                                                          
  .
  .
  .
  .
 250       0      -1     1       1      0       0      0     -1                    0       -1
```

I am not able to solve it and really appreciate if someone could help me out; Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following steps, the trick is to use column index to getting the correct column sequences:

```
# create copied data and concat into original
df2 = pd.concat([df, df.replace(0,-1).fillna(0).drop('ID', axis=1)], 1)

# since column names are same, we need to use index
cols = [x for x in df2.columns if x != 'ID']
cols = dict(enumerate(cols))

# get correct index for column names
cols_index = [x[0] for x in sorted(cols.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])]

# fix column names
idcol = df2[['ID']]
df2 = df2.drop('ID', 1).iloc[:,cols_index]

# add the ID column
df2 = pd.concat([idcol, df2], 1).fillna(0)

print(df2)

   ID  col1  col1  col2  col2  col3  col3
0   1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1   2   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2   3   NaN  -1.0   NaN  -1.0   NaN  -1.0
3   4   NaN  -1.0   NaN  -1.0   NaN  -1.0
4   5   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
```

> **Sample Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': list(range(1,6)),
                   'col1':[1,0,np.NaN,np.NaN,1],
                   'col2':[1,0,np.NaN,np.NaN,1],
                   'col3':[1,0,np.NaN,np.NaN,1]})
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks its working especially the order of the desired columns but in the original column (not copied), the nan values are not replaced with zeros but i can do that and also the -1 replacement was not for nan values but only if the value in original column cell is 0 then the copied cell should have a -1 that i can correct as well. Thanks a lot...

Comment: @codeDB thanks for the feedback, I've updated the answer. If it helped, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi, sorry i just realized a mistake in my data. The condition of value replacement was wrong. If the original cell (col1) has a value of 1 then the same copied copied cell (col1) should have -1 and original cell keeps value of 1. Similarly if the original cell has a value of 0 then this 0 of original cell should be changed to -1 and the value of same copied cell should have a value of 1. For empty cells the rule is same both original and copied should be filled with 0's. I tried it with df.replace({a:b,b:c}) function but it did not work. Can you please help me out for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to see if it works.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Starting Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,0,np.NaN,np.NaN,1],'col2':[1,0,np.NaN,np.NaN,1],'col3':[1,0,np.NaN,np.NaN,1]})
```

First make a copy of the original df.

```
df_copy = df.copy()
```

Then replace the values in the copy based on criteria above.

```
columns =  df_copy.columns
df_copy[columns] = np.where(df_copy[columns]==0,-1,df_copy[columns])
```

Then fill the blank values with 0.

```
df_copy = df_copy.fillna(0)
```

Add a column count for sorting.

```
df.loc['total'] = np.arange(len(df.columns))
df_copy.loc['total'] = np.arange(len(df_copy.columns))
```

Then concatenate the two df's together

```
new_df = pd.concat([df,df_copy],axis=1)
```

Sort the columns using the column count row, then drop the row from the new df

```
new_df = new_df.sort_values(by='total',axis=1)
new_df = new_df.loc[~new_df.index.isin(['total'])]
```

Comment: no, its giving two errors: A:  "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fillna"    if i place fillna before the np.where line then the second error is:   B: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid.

Comment: I removed the errors and now its working but the output file is not what i required.

Comment: did you import pandas as pd and numpy as np?

Comment: I reviewed the code and realized i skipped a step... revised above

Comment: Thanks for the help  and i ran the code but sorry its not giving the desired output although its replacing the values based on the condition but only in copied dataframe which is the second half of the file and  also there are empty cells and the order which i mentioned is not there as the order is important, i mean copied cell should be after the original cell like col1 col1 col2 col2 whereas concatenate does give this order

Comment: Okay i have edited the post one more time. It includes the logic to get the order you would like. You can fill in the blank values in the original df with whatever you would like by using `.fillna()`

Comment: there are more than 1000 columns and more than 150 rows so will starting data work ? as its not possible to manually write all of that..

Comment: ok i will experiment with it and will post the updates

Comment: The starting data was just for me to test the code on a small dataset. You would use your data instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and i will try it and will let you know. I will also try to first duplicate the columns and then change the values based on required conditions to also have an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (similar approach as other answer with use of pandas built-in functions to replace):

```
df2 = df.copy().replace(0,-1).fillna(0).drop(['ID'],1)
df = pd.concat([df.fillna(0),df2],1)
```

output and sample input (for a different input sample, but the comparison of columns are apparent):

input:

```
     ID  col1  col2  col3  col4  col1000
0     1     1     0     1   1.0      NaN
1     2     0     1     1   NaN      NaN
2     3     1     0     0   NaN      NaN
250   250     0     1     0   0.0      NaN
```

output:

```
    ID  col1  col2  col3  col4 ... col1000  col1  col2  col3  col4 ... col1000
0    1     1     0     1   1.0      0.0     1    -1     1   1.0      0.0
1    2     0     1     1   0.0      0.0    -1     1     1   0.0      0.0
2    3     1     0     0   0.0      0.0     1    -1    -1   0.0      0.0
...
250  250     0     1     0   0.0      0.0    -1     1    -1  -1.0      0.0
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but is there a way to maintain the order which i require ? I have to further process the data and for that i need the same order which i mentioned in the output file in question. Each copied column must be after the original column like col1 col1 col2 col2  col3 col3 and son on as otherwise it does not serve the purpose.

Comment: There are more than 10000 columns and more than 250 rows so its not possible to compare them manually

Comment: @codeDB Do you care if they have the same column names or can they have for example suffix in their name `col1_old` and `col1_new`?

Comment: Hi Ehsan no problem for that but the order and the position of the columns should not chnage